# Error in installation laravel medialibrary 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, media-library

Hi everyone I'm trying to install media library in laravel 7.4 but it have bellow error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for symfony/console 5.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v5.0.1].
- Installation request for spatie/laravel-medialibrary ^8.1 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-medialibrary[8.1.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v5.0.1, 4.4.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[4.4.x-dev, v5.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[4.4.x-dev, v5.0.1].
- Conclusion: install symfony/process 4.4.x-dev
- Installation request for symfony/process 5.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v5.0.1].
```

Whats wrong with this package, As here [link](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) explains the package I resolve requirements :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable": "^5.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "morilog/jalali": "^3.1",
    "santigarcor/laratrust": "^5.2",
    "symfony/console": "5.0.1",
    "symfony/process": "5.0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The Medialibrary package requires [exif extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php) . Enable this extension from the php.ini file.